# Как отследить прокрутку страницы до определенного блока?

Tags: javascript, jquery

На странице при прокрутке до определенного блока включаю анимацию:

```
$(window).on('load scroll', function() { 
    if ($(this).scrollTop() >= '3450' && CountUpFlag == 0) {
        CountUp();
        CountUpFlag = 1;
    }
});
```

Делал на маленьком разрешении экрана, и анимация появлялась, как только блок попадала в зону видимости.
Но если смотреть на большом разрешении экрана, то анимация включается, когда блок уже практически прокрутили.
Как можно отследить прокрутку до определенного блока без привязки к `scrollTop()`, чтобы анимация на всех разрешениях включалась сразу после появления блока в зоне видимости?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Для определения появления блока (как минимум 1 его пикселя, при условии что блок попадает в экран по горизонтали) на экране при прокручивании сверху вниз, достаточно сравнивать сумму `.scrollTop()` и `.height()` для `window` с вертикальным смещением блока относительно верха страницы (`.offset().top`):

```js
$(function() {
    var blockTop = $('.second').offset().top;
    var CountUpFlag = 0;
    var $window = $(window);
    $window.on('load scroll', function() {
        var top = $window.scrollTop();
        var height = $window.height();
        if (top + height >= blockTop && CountUpFlag == 0) {
            CountUp();
            CountUpFlag = 1;
        }
    });
    function CountUp() {
        $('#animation').show();
    }
});
```

```css
.first {
    height: 1500px;
}
.second {
    border: 1px solid;
    height: 200px;
}
#animation {
    position: fixed;
    display: none;
}
```

```html
<div id="animation">Time for animation</div>
<div>
    <div class="first"></div>
    <div class="second"></div>
    <div class="first"></div>
</div>

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

При прокручивании страницы снизу вверх, нужно сравнивать сумму вертикального смещения и высоты блока с `.scrollTop()` для `window`.

Также вместо написания своего кода можно использовать соответствующий плагин. Например, [jQuery.appear](https://github.com/morr/jquery.appear).